# Hibernate Spring Transactional no transaction is in progress

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

I'm trying to get hibernate working with spring managed transactions. No matter what I do I always get 'no transaction is in progress' exception. The only thing I don't understand is this:

If I don't call `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` in my `@Transactional` method, everything goes fine and I can see `HibernateTransactionManager` transaction lifecycle methods being called - `doGetTransaction(...), doCommit(...)` etc. and no error is thrown.

When I add `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` in my method I still see `doGetTransaction()` (obviously), but as soon as `getCurrentSession()` is called I'm starting to see `doRollback()` and in the end I'm getting 'no transaction is in progress' exception. I've already spent whole day on it, hope someone helps. Tried changing transaction scope, xml configuration, basically everything I can think of. Using latest spring and hibernate versions (4.3.3 and 5.2.3 respectively)

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/trainings"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="username" value="xxx"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager" >
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="webtrainings.beans"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

GenericDAO.java:

```
@Repository("genericDao")
@Scope(value = "singleton")
public class GenericDAO<T> {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    public void getAll(Class<T> clazz) {
        factory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

MyService.java:

```
@Service("myService")
@Transactional
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    GenericDAO genericDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void hehe() {
        genericDAO.getAll(Training.class);
    }
}
```

HelloController.java:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome")
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                              HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("hello");
        model.addObject("msg", "hello world");
        myService.hehe();

        return model;
    }
}
```

spring-servlet.xml (mvc):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="webtrainings.utils"/>

<bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Stacktrace:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3430)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1397)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1393)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:144)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:95)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:932)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:744)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:487)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    webtrainings.beans.MyService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3fca725c.hehe(<generated>)
    webtrainings.utils.HelloController.handleRequestInternal(HelloController.java:32)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Can you check what the type of the class is that you get via  factory.getCurrentSession()

Comment: try to make interface for genericDao, and then implement it. or add @Transactional to getAll(..)

Comment: Could you post a stacktrace?

Comment: The object I'm getting from `getCurrentSession()` is SessionImpl

Comment: To clarify: method executes till the end even when I call `getCurrentSession()`. It's just that if I do call it inside I get exception after method completes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the problem is in using Java DCEVM with HotswapAgent. When I remove   `-XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:C:\hotswap-agent.jar` from tomcat run configuration everything works as expected. I guess this is one of the side effects of using "hacky" software. My knowledge in these things is too small to even try to guess what the actual problem is.

Comment: Indeed. There seems to be a problem with the Hibernate plugin.Disable that one and you can still take full advantage of the hotswap functionality that DVEVEM provides. (see https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent/issues/187)

Comment: After spending a couple of days iterating over different solutions, this is the only fix that I need in order to get past this frustrating issue.

Answer (score 0):

facing the same problem on springboot project, solved by config adding config like:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction=true
```